# Pubsubhubbub - Transient error with every Topic URL

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, websub

We subscribed to YouTube's Pubsubhubbub to get notified if someone published a video on a channel. If we try to look at our Subscription details or the Topic url details through https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/ everything shows a "Transient Error" and the Server returns a 503 Error.
And it seems to error with every Topic-Url i try. Our Topic Url if it's opened in a browser, however, shows content, so it seems to be right. (https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCyjzn-6YZur2M-qVwTzbQGA)

It worked for a few weeks and yesterday we tried to subscribe to another channel und now this error is everywhere. Even our old subscribe won't get any push notifications anymore and the old topic url returns an error, too.

Anyone knows where the problem could be? Or has the same problem?

Comment: I am trying the same thing, I haven't succeeded in getting a callback at my callback URL, I am trying to do it with nodejs endpoint in Amazon Lambda, any help with respect to materials you used to create the endpoint or a code copy of your endpoint for reference will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sending back the hub.challenge value? is your GET method working still?